# Adding entry to program header table

Tags: header, elf, static-analysis

I have a .bin file that I'm analysing in Ghidra, I define it as an ELF in Ghidra but therefore every byte that's loaded, has to be part of a segment in the program header table.

The whole .bin file comes from a dump which isnt really that important, but there's a series of bytes that Ghidra doesn't read because it isn't in the program header table. So I want to add another entry to the program header table, the issue is that there isn't enough space left to add this entry without overwriting the PT_INTERP. I was thinking about shifting everything but then I have to change every absolute reference mentioned in the binary.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this safely and properly. I did some research but there are no tools I can find (like ELF tool chain) that can resolve my issue, therefore I hope that someone here has some knowledge to help me out!